# Unable to instantiate receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm getting "Unable to instantiate receiver" errors when sending intents to my app. It seems Eclipse somehow cannot see my `ExIntentReceiver` class. I don't know why it happens; ExIntentReceiver is in the same package (com.example.app).

ExIntentReceiver.java:

```
package com.example.app

public class ExIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
  if(action.equals("com.example.app.START_SERVICE"))    {
        Log.v("service", "is started");
      } else if(action.equals("com.example.app.STOP_SERVICE"))  {
          Log.v("service", "is stopped");
      }

   }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".ExIntentReceiver" android:exported="true">  
      <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.example.app.START_SERVICE" />
       <action android:name="com.example.app.STOP_SERVICE" />
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

logcat:

```
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.app.ExIntentReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.app.ExIntentReceiver
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2261)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.app.ExIntentReceiver
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-22 10:37:13.361: E/AndroidRuntime(11213):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
```

Comment: The class is `ExtIntentReceiver`but in the manifest file you have `ExIntentReceiver`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have action declared in their own intent filter.

```
<receiver android:name=".ExtIntentReceiver " android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.STOP_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Apart from that make sure you give correct package name to `Receiver` inside manifest.
And make sure you should spell it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have BroadcastReceiver as inner class and you want to use it without making instance of it you should make it STATIC like this

```
public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by making the Receiver a public class